# user template tag disappearing in django for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

in my django template I have this basic code.  the {{ user.id }} displays as long as I'm outside of the for loop.  Inside the for loop nothing is returned or displayed.   Totally frustrated right now.  permission(perms) does not work inside the for loop.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<table>
<tr>
     <td colspan=2">{{ user.id }}</td>
</tr>
{% for item in object_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

EDIT:  Why does user.id not show up in the for loop?

item.title displays correctly.  the first time use {{ user.id }} id displays.  Any user.id called in for loop does not display.  This is the most simplified version of the code I have tried and it just doesn't want to work.  Anyone have any ideas?

RESOLVED:  I was using a render_to_response() but not including user context data.  I switched to render() and all of the relevant RequestContext data was included which includes user data.

Comment: Post a sample object list

Comment: If nothing in the for loop is being displayed, object_list must be empty.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you want that table displayed. The first row outside of the loop has a single column. The row inside the loop has two columns.

Comment: Unfortunately,even your edit hardly makes anything clear to expect help.  The edit should have ideally included a sample data set and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I am guessing that you are trying to loop through a dictionary.

If you wish to iterate through a dictionary,refer the following code snippet-

`data = {'a': [ [1, 2] ], 'b': [ [3, 4] ],'c':[ [5,6]] }`

Now iterate through the items as follows-

```
<table>

    {% for key, values in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        {% for v in values[0] %}
        <td>{{v}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I modified the question to be a bit more clear.  I'm wondering why user.id showing up inside the for loop.